# Can't add NOT NULL constraint using liquibase

Tags: sql, postgresql, constraints, liquibase

I have a task by which I should do the next steps (using liquibase):

1. Add a new field to the existing table (someNewField);
2. Update all existing data (for all existing data someNewField = "someValue");
3. After that I need to make someNewField NOT NULL.

My solution (doesn't work):

```
<databaseChangeLog
        xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog
                      http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.8.xsd">

    <changeSet id="1-update-table" author="fatumepta">

        <preConditions onFail="MARK_RAN">
            <not>
                <columnExists tableName="customer" columnName="last_name"/>
            </not>
        </preConditions>

        <sql>
            <!-- add a new text field -->
            ALTER TABLE customer ADD COLUMN last_name text;
            <!-- update already existing data -->
            UPDATE customer SET last_name = 'unknown' WHERE last_name IS NULL;
            <!-- make field mandatory -->
            ALTER TABLE customer MODIFY last_name SET text NOT_NULL;
        </sql>
    </changeSet>

</databaseChangeLog>
```

I can't do the 3rd step -> getting error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/liquibase/LiquibaseAutoConfiguration$LiquibaseConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is liquibase.exception.MigrationFailedException: Migration failed for change set classpath:db/changelog/changelog-3.1.xml::2-update-table::fatumepta:
     Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "MODIFY"
  Позиция: 22 [Failed SQL: (0) ALTER TABLE customer MODIFY last_name text NOT_NULL]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1788) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:609) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:531) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1161) ~[spring-context-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:915) ~[spring-context-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:588) ~[spring-context-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:144) ~[spring-boot-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:767) [spring-boot-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) [spring-boot-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:426) [spring-boot-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:326) [spring-boot-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1309) [spring-boot-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1298) [spring-boot-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at edu.liquibase.example.LiquibaseExampleApplication.main(LiquibaseExampleApplication.java:19) [classes/:na]
Caused by: liquibase.exception.MigrationFailedException: Migration failed for change set classpath:db/changelog/changelog-3.1.xml::2-update-table::fatumepta:
     Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "MODIFY"
  Позиция: 22 [Failed SQL: (0) ALTER TABLE customer MODIFY last_name text NOT_NULL]
    at liquibase.changelog.ChangeSet.execute(ChangeSet.java:659) ~[liquibase-core-3.10.3.jar:na]
    at liquibase.changelog.visitor.UpdateVisitor.visit(UpdateVisitor.java:53) ~[liquibase-core-3.10.3.jar:na]
    at liquibase.changelog.ChangeLogIterator.run(ChangeLogIterator.java:97) ~[liquibase-core-3.10.3.jar:na]
    at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:201) ~[liquibase-core-3.10.3.jar:na]
    at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:178) ~[liquibase-core-3.10.3.jar:na]
    at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.performUpdate(SpringLiquibase.java:368) ~[liquibase-core-3.10.3.jar:na]
    at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet(SpringLiquibase.java:316) ~[liquibase-core-3.10.3.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1847) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1784) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "MODIFY"
  Позиция: 22 [Failed SQL: (0) ALTER TABLE customer MODIFY last_name text NOT_NULL]
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor$ExecuteStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcExecutor.java:430) ~[liquibase-core-3.10.3.jar:na]
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:87) ~[liquibase-core-3.10.3.jar:na]
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:159) ~[liquibase-core-3.10.3.jar:na]
    at liquibase.database.AbstractJdbcDatabase.execute(AbstractJdbcDatabase.java:1276) ~[liquibase-core-3.10.3.jar:na]
    at liquibase.database.AbstractJdbcDatabase.executeStatements(AbstractJdbcDatabase.java:1258) ~[liquibase-core-3.10.3.jar:na]
    at liquibase.changelog.ChangeSet.execute(ChangeSet.java:622) ~[liquibase-core-3.10.3.jar:na]
    ... 27 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "MODIFY"
  Позиция: 22
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2553) ~[postgresql-42.2.18.jar:42.2.18]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2285) ~[postgresql-42.2.18.jar:42.2.18]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:323) ~[postgresql-42.2.18.jar:42.2.18]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:473) ~[postgresql-42.2.18.jar:42.2.18]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:393) ~[postgresql-42.2.18.jar:42.2.18]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:322) ~[postgresql-42.2.18.jar:42.2.18]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeCachedSql(PgStatement.java:308) ~[postgresql-42.2.18.jar:42.2.18]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:284) ~[postgresql-42.2.18.jar:42.2.18]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:279) ~[postgresql-42.2.18.jar:42.2.18]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.execute(ProxyStatement.java:95) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.execute(HikariProxyStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor$ExecuteStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcExecutor.java:426) ~[liquibase-core-3.10.3.jar:na]
    ... 32 common frames omitted
```

Please, help me. I don't understand what i am doing wrong!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html) you need to use `alter` instead of `modify`, it must be `NOT NULL` (no underscore) and there is no need to repeat the data type:

```
ALTER TABLE customer ALTER last_name SET NOT NULL;
```

Comment: doesn't work at least for liquibase. Almost the same error.

Comment: Ah, copy & paste error. I didn't see the underscore in `NOT_NULL` - which obviously is wrong as well